# How to use variables with regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is the input string: `23x^45*y or 2x^2 or y^4*x^3`.

I am matching `^[0-9]+` after letter `x`. In other words I am matching `x` followed by `^` followed by numbers. Problem is that I don't know that I am matching `x`, it could be any letter that I stored as variable in my char array.

For example:

```
foreach (char cEle in myarray) // cEle is letter in char array x, y, z, ...
{
    match CEle in regex(input) //PSEUDOCODE
}
```

I am new to regex and I new that this can be done if I define regex variables, but I don't know how.

Comment: Thanks dtb for formatting! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pattern `@"[cEle]\^\d+"` which you can create dynamically from your character array:

```
string s = "23x^45*y or 2x^2 or y^4*x^3";
char[] letters = { 'e', 'x', 'L' };
string regex = string.Format(@"[{0}]\^\d+",
    Regex.Escape(new string(letters)));
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, regex))
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```

Result:

```
x^45
x^2
x^3
```

A few things to note:

- It is necessary to escape the `^` inside the regular expression otherwise it has a special meaning "start of line".
- It is a good idea to use `Regex.Escape` when inserting literal strings from a user into a regular expression, to avoid that any characters they type get misinterpreted as special characters.
- This will also match the x from the end of variables with longer names like `tax^2`. This can be avoided by requiring a word boundary (`\b`).
- If you write `x^1` as just `x` then this regular expression will not match it. This can be fixed by using `(\^\d+)?`.

Comment: Yes, word boundary is important. +1 :)

Comment: Never use `Regex.Escape` to escape arbitrary chars used inside a character class since this method is only meant to escape those chars that are considered special *outside* of a character class. If the list contains `]` somewhere inside [it will close the character class earlier than expected](https://ideone.com/Z7mA3v).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and faster way to implement from my point of view is the following:

> Input: This?_isWhat?IWANT

```
        string tokenRef = "?";
        Regex pattern = new Regex($@"([^{tokenRef}\/>]+)");
```

The pattern should remove my tokenRef and storing the following output:

- Group1   This
- Group2   _isWhat
- Group3   IWANT

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pattern for capturing the number but excluding the x^ prefix:

`(?<=x\^)[0-9]+`

```
string strInput = "23x^45*y or 2x^2 or y^4*x^3";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(strInput, @"(?<=x\^)[0-9]+"))
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```

This should print :

```
45
2
3
```

Do not forget to use the option `IgnoreCase` for matching, if required.

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question, I want to capture ^ but I don't know how to use variable as my pattern